# Overlay image over another android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I have photo album which shows the image as rounded with white border. Image will be adding dynamically. I tried frame layout but it it not working for me. My try : Adding dynamic image over already existing round shape image..

```
<FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="60dip"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imagef"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ph_bg" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Above xml not giving exact result .. any idea ?

Comment: Can you post what should be result?

Comment: i want my dynamically generated image as background and the static as foreground..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagef"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ph_bg" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will do your task.

***Happy coding :)***

Answer (score 1):

Try setting foreground and background on only one `ImageView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/your_img_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/the_actual_image"
        android:src="@drawable/the_image_overlay" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how can we set Foreground on ImageView?

Comment: Use the android:src... that is the foreground.